Erro no deploy de um servidor, erro => sh: 1: prisma: Permission denied ==> Build failed
To usando o render para colocar uma api para a produção, porém, essa mensagem de erro não para de aparecer, ja instalei o prisma globalmente e nada adianta. Os comandos que estou usando para build são: npm install && npx prisma migrate deploy && npm run build. Assim que chega no npx prisma migrate deploy ele ja falha. Meu package.json ta da seguinte forma:
{
"name": "server_sistema_estoque",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"start": "node build/server.js",
"dev": "node --watch --import=tsx src/server.ts",
"migrate": "prisma migrate deploy"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"description": "",
"devDependencies": {
"@types/express": "^5.0.0",
"@types/node": "^22.10.2",
"prisma": "^6.0.1",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2",
"tsx": "^4.19.2",
"typescript": "^5.7.2",
"watch": "^1.0.2"
},
"dependencies": {
"@prisma/client": "^6.0.1",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.4.7",
"express": "^4.21.2",
"helmet": "^8.0.0",
"prisma": "^6.0.1"
}
}
Aparece esse erro no render:
sh: 1: prisma: Permission denied ==> Build failed
Tentei instalar o prisma globalmente e não adianta.
